# "Not a git repository"

Tags: git

I am trying to use a program that uses git as the backing store (I am new to git).  On initialization, this program does a:

```
"git" "--bare" "rev-parse" "refs/heads/index"
```

Which results in:

`fatal: Not a git repository: '/home/david/blog.git'`

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gittutorial.html), `git init`, `git add test.txt` and `git commit`. The repo seems to behave properly when (in the correct directory) I do (for example):

```
$ git status
```

What is `rev-parse` doing and what do I have to do to my repo to make it work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If `git status` is working then you must be in a non-bare repository with a working tree. `git status` requires a working tree.

If the program is running `git --bare ...` then it expects the given directory to be a bare git repository, i.e. with not working directory.

The naming convention of `reponame.git` is usually reserved for bare repositores and non-bare repositories usually use a directory name of `reponame` and contain a `.git` subdirectory.

If `/home/david/blog.git` is actually a non-bare repository then it will have a `.git` subdirectory. If this is the case you can probably point the program at `/home/david/blog.git/.git` but I can't help feeling that it would be safer to point it at a truly bare repository. What program is it and what were the instructions for initializing its data store?
`

Comment: Thanks - that's cleared things up a lot.  Now, how do I make `refs/heads/index`?  (I can see only `master` in the `refs/heads` directory).  

The program is "tekuti" (http://wingolog.org/software/tekuti/) and it recommends to migrate the store from wordpress (which I have not used, so don't have).

Comment: Are you sure that you *need* to make a branch called `index`? Might tekuti be checking whether the branch exists so that it can make it with it own content? (If you do need to make it `git branch index` should work.)

Comment: Spot on!  (Perhaps the easiest path is to use Wordpress after all...)

Answer (score 6):

Maybe "git init" is all you need to do.

Comment: Try `git init --bare` instead.  As the other answer points out, what he needs is just the `.git` directory and not a working directory to go with it.

Comment: Thanks - I edited the question so that it is apparent that I did that.