# Why do some repository URLs end in .git while others don't?

Tags: git, url, github, git-clone

When I clone a repository, is there any difference between these two URLs?

1. Without .git extension:

   ```
   git clone http://foo/repo
   ```
2. With .git extension:

   ```
   git clone http://foo/repo.git
   ```

Comment: if you are referring to Github URLs the .git is optional

Comment: You might be interested in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1734421/164966) answer.  Specifically *The naming convention of reponame.git is usually reserved for bare repositores ...*

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The convention is that the *.git* extension should be used for bare repositories, and left off of directories with a working tree. Git doesn't really care, but has a few convenience methods that make this fairly transparent.

For example, if you have a repository named **/tmp/foo.git** and you call `git clone file:///tmp/foo`, Git will first try to find **/tmp/foo**. If it doesn't exist, it will try **/tmp/foo.git** instead.

This does *not* work the other way around. If your directory is named **/tmp/foo** and you try to clone from **/tmp/foo.git** you will be told:

> fatal: '/tmp/foo.git' does not appear to be a git repository

Most of the HTTP/HTTPS functionality is from your web server, not Git. Even if you're using [Smart HTTP transport](http://git-scm.com/2010/03/04/smart-http.html), I suspect most of the magic happens in a server-side LocationMatch directive. Theory aside, some quick tests against GitHub show that it works the same way as the SSH and Git procotols in that respect, but your mileage may vary on other web servers.

Comment: I thought that the smart http capability was a wrapper on the git side, so that the server side is simply providing an HTTP response. https://github.com/blog/642-smart-http-support but http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.3/git-http-backend.html suggest I was wrong and it is a bit of server functionality.