# whats exect difference between githuburl and githuburl.git?

Tags: git, github

I mean whats exact difference between this https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon and https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon.git

Comment: The difference is supposed to be that the first url (without .git) is the web interface whereas the second url (with .git) is the git api, that git itself talks to. However, github adds redirects and supports the relevant protocols both places and both ways depending on the client you point to it, so there may not be an actual difference in practice. You can point a web browser to either, and you'll get redirected to the first url, and you can point git at either and it will work just fine.

Comment: My guess is that there used to be a difference, but apparently there no longer is. I seem to remember using the web interface url to try to clone from a long time ago and that failed, but now it works.

Comment: This should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068576/why-do-some-repository-urls-end-in-git-while-others-dont