# When attempting to mirror a Git repo I receive a "not a git repository" error

Tags: git, git-mirror

I'm attempting to do this:

https://help.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/duplicating-a-repository#mirroring-a-repository-in-another-location

The clone creats a `[repo].git` folder which only has an `objects` folder within it, and when I try to add the origin URL from with the created folder, I receive the `not a git repository` error because there is no `.git` folder in the `[repo].git` folder.

What am I missing?

---

These are the commands I'm using

`git clone --mirror [URL]`

`cd [repo folder]`

`git remote set-url --push origin [new URL]` <-- This is where I recieve the error

`git push origin --mirror`

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734327/not-a-git-repository

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up getting to work. I'm not sure if the last push of tags is actually needed, but I threw it in for good measure

```
git clone --mirror [URL]
cd [repo folder]
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin [new URL] 
git push origin --mirror
git push --tags
```